# Implement a brute force algorithm to find three missing word from BIP39 seed

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, passphrase

I lost 3 middle words of my 24 words seed phrase for a nano ledger hardware wallet.

As an example (not my real seed phrase)

```
pledge horror unfair category a.... xxxxxx a...... core abuse tenant crew captain insect angry again deposit detail similar arrest kind copy pony door brass
```

So I know the missing words in position 5 and 7 start with `a` and I don't have any clue for word number 6.

I know for sure an ethereum public address that I used back in 2017, but I am not sure about my BTC address.

I believe that cracking the seed phrase is doable, but as I am not a programmer (I have a beginner level in python for data science) I don't know how to do it.

So far, I have explored:

- [BTCRecover](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover) but it only handles one missing word and 3 typos
- [Seed Savior](https://3rditeration.github.io/mnemonic-recovery/src/index.html) but it only handles 1 missing words

Does anyone know how to solve this problem in a practical manner?
I understand that the theoretical solution to this problem is trivial but I need to implement it, which is far from trivial for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use BTCRecover (My updated fork here: https://github.com/3rdIteration/btcrecover) with all the defaults except for adding --big-typos 3

When prompted for your seed, just put in an X in place of the invalid words. (Any placeholder will do as long as it's not a BIP39 word)

If you are even slightly unsure of your address, run it once (with what you think it is) and if it doesn't find anything, run it against an AddressDB. (https://btcrecover.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Creating_and_Using_AddressDB/)

Either way it should take a few days to search all possible seeds each time, so quite straightfoward as far as seed recoveries go.

Comment: Thank you again, I'll try and let everyone know if it worked.

Comment: So I managed to use your tool to recover my seed phrase. It took me a little while, so I will share my experience, as it might help others:

Comment: On a 2017 macbook pro and a PC with a 3.2GHz i7 16 GB, I had an insufficient memory bug. Using `--no-dupcheck` solved that first issue. I then ran BTCrecover on the i7 PC as it was much faster. It took 8 hours to explore all possible seeds, but it failed. I suspected that it was because of the BTC address that I was unsure, so as you adviced, I used the `--addressdb` but it failed again. I guess my BTC address was maybe not in the right format (P2SH instead or P2KH)

Comment: Finally, I ran the sofware with the Eth address  against the ethereum address database `python seedrecover.py --no-dupchecks --addr-limit 2 --bip32-path "m/44'/60'/0'" --big-typos 3 --addressdb ./btcrecover/addresses-ETH.db --wallet-type bip39` . Note that the derivation is the ledger lagacy one, so if you have a seed phrase from a more recent version, you should use `"m/44'/60'/0'/0'"`

Comment: And I forgot: a bug report @Crypto Guide: the script imports the "Crypto" module, while the downloaded one as no capital letter, it is "crypto" so I received a `NoModuleFound` error. The workaround was to change the name of the module to "Crypto"

Comment: If you got a bug like that then report it here: https://github.com/3rdIteration/btcrecover/issues and include the full error so that I can know exactly where to check. (That is very odd as the CI tests cover Windows, Linux and Mac, so it should have picked that up automatically)

Comment: It should have worked for the BTC address DB, regardless of the address format. You were manually using the --bip-32 path command when you could have just left that off entirely and gone with the defaults, so I'm thinking that you may have not specified the correct derivation path for the BTC account. (The only argument you needed was the --big-typos 3, the wallet type, addr limit, etc, could all have been selected in gui or left as the defaults)

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these, I’ve seen guys break into accounts that were missing 8 words with the solver-server.

BIP39-Solver-CPU: This is the CPU benchmark tool he wrote in Rust to get an idea of how long it will take do solve on a CPU for certain number of unknown words.

https://github.com/johncantrell97/bip39-solver-cpu

BIP39-Solver-GPU: This is the actual GPU version he ran on each worker GPU to solve this problem.

https://github.com/johncantrell97/bip39-solver-gpu

BIP39-Solver-Server: This is the actual server he ran that handled distributing the work to all the workers.

https://github.com/johncantrell97/bip39-solver-server

Comment: Interesting work, thank you for your contribution. But the problem with such solution is that I don't understand the code in rust very well (my knowledge is limited to R and Python) so it is difficult for me to tweak it. Specifically It looks like he is checking the seed against a bitcoin child pubKey, but not against ethereum pubKey.

Comment: You might be able to contact John, he’s usually pretty helpful, you’d have to agree to a percentage though.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I finally managed to recover my seed phrase thanks to BTCRecover tools as explained by @cryptoguide. I was more confortable with python to solve the little hurdles on my road...